# How to declare type for functional React component using object destructuring in props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-props

I am still learning TypeScript and declaring (advanced) types. I am trying to convert my CRA project to typescript and I have following component in it. How I should declare the types for this?

This component is almost 1:1 from react-router-dom examples, but I couldn't find any example showing this written in TypeScript

```js
// ProtectedContent.tsx

import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Auth from '../services/Auth';

const ProtectedContent = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => {
      if (Auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        return (
          <Component {...props} />
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/auth/signin',
            state: { from: props.location },
          }} />
        );
      }
    }} />
  );
};

export default ProtectedContent;
```

I tried creating an interface for the parameters:

```js
interface PCProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>{
  component: React.Component;
}

const ProtectedContent = ({ component: Component, ...rest }: PCProps) => {
   // .......
}
```

But then I was having problem with the line

```js
return (
  <Component {...props} />
);
```

as there was error saying

> JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures. ts(2604)

Then when I was trying to fix that I ended going down an insane rabbit hole and lost track and understanding of what was going on anymore.

So how should I declare the types for this so that the component could be any React component and then destructure rest of the props neatly?

TS version is 3.8.3

---

Edit: (Possible solution)

From the depths of internet I found this "solution". I can declare the component in the PCProps interface as 'ReactType' and the use it like this:

```js
interface PCProps {
  component: React.ReactType;
}

const ProtectedContent = ({ component: Component, ...rest }): PCProps => {
  ...
}
```

This will get rid of the error, but why? What is this 'ReactType'? I went through the docs and found nothing related to it. Is there anyone experienced in React and TS who could explain this and also how this kind of component should be typed?

I don't really like to use this solution, because I have no idea what's happening.

[Solution source](http://htykuut.blogspot.com/2019/01/typescript-3-jsx-element-type-component.html)

---

Edit2:

Sandbox showing original, proposed solution using React.FC and possible solution using React.ReactType. Check all the three files in this sandbox.

[Sandbox for this question](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-shaw-5pc60?file=/src/ProtectedContentOriginal.tsx)

Comment: In [my project](https://github.com/AlexanderDerck/spotify-playlist-manager/blob/development/src/containers/PrivateRoute/PrivateRoute.tsx) I recently did it like this: `export interface PrivateRouteProps extends RouteProps, StateProps {}`

Comment: Can you confirm your file extension is .tsx and not .ts?

Comment: @gqstav yes, the file extension is .tsx

Comment: @AlexanderDerck Could you explain your solution a little?

Comment: OK, try declaring `component: React.FC;` which works fine here: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-hamilton-1xuyu?file=/src/App.tsx:95-97

Comment: @zaplec The `PrivateRouteProps` interface that describes the props of my component directly extends the `RouteProps` interface of `react-router-dom` (instead of extending `HtmlAttributes<>` like you do in your solution). No problems at all like that.

Comment: @gqstav using React.FC will just end up having the error in the Component part to refer to some History<PoorMansUnknown>. Check my comment for wentjun's answer

Comment: Could you share a sandbox reproducing the issue?

Comment: @gqstav I'll try to create one soon

Comment: @gqstav Added link to sandbox in the question. There are 3 files. One showing the original and 2 showing your React.FC solution and then the ReactType way I found.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file extension is `.tsx` and not `.ts` and that you're declaring `component: React.FC;`. Working example: codesandbox.io/s/silly-hamilton-1xuyu?file=/src/App.tsx:95-97

Comment: Is it compulsory ?

Comment: Well, .ts files are plain old Typescript files and do not support adding JSX Elements, such as `component` in this case.

Comment: I guess it is not suggested but we can still use it.